# User-defined variables race condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, race-condition

If I have an API endpoint that runs two queries: the first initialising some user-defined variables, the next using them to query some stuff.

```
set @variable = 0;
select @variable := @variable + 1 from table1;
```

Then imagine the second query is fairly slow, and someone hits the endpoint before it finishes. That resets the `@variable`, correct? Meaning if I have a very frequent API point the queries will not be correct.

1. If this concern is correct, what is the go-to method to prevent such thing?
2. Should I make it into an procedured statement instead?
3. Would wrapping in a transaction help?

Comment: `@variable` is used for the current session and connection.